# Unable to import scipy after installing Anaconda2.4.0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, anaconda

I'm trying to import numpy and scipy in Python 2.7.10 on Windows

I've been unable to install scipy via pip or the binaries supplied at:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

But I had heard that Anaconda comes standard with numpy and scipy. It's worth noting I can successfully import numpy.

```
conda list
```

prints out all packages and scipy is one of them but the import still fails.

When I run

```
$ conda install scipy
```

This is what I see:

```
$ conda install scipy
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..................
Package plan for installation in environment c:\Users\Nick\Anaconda2:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

conda-env: 2.4.4-py27_1

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Linking packages ...
"Ensuring that c:\Users\Nick\Anaconda2\Library\bin is on user PATH environment variable."
"" was unexpected at this time.
Error: Error: post-link failed for: conda-env-2.4.4-py27_1
```

When I run

```
$ conda install -f scipy
```

This is what I see:

```
$ conda install -f scipy
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..................
Package plan for installation in environment c:\Users\Nick\Anaconda2:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

scipy: 0.16.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.16.0-np110py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
```

It appears to be working but when I then try to import scipy at the top of my Python program, I get:

```
$ python steps.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "steps.py", line 16, in <module>
    import scipy as st
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Am I doing the import wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that Anaconda has not been properly installed on your path. Try running you run `python --version` and `where python` from the command prompt. Does it look like it's the Anaconda python?

Comment: Might be a bug discussed here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1786 – get a look.

Comment: I get the same problem

Comment: @JoshAdel 

`$ python --version`
`Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)`

Comment: @JoshAdel exactly what I see too...were you able to solve?

Comment: I have a colleague that is getting the exact same error. We can import numpy, matplotlib, etc. However, import scipy fails.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, especially of [github.com/conda/conda/issues/1786](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1786) I believe  Anaconda 2.4.0 fails for scipy. The solution is to get a newer version of Anaconda or consider installing the latest Miniconda.

Comment: My colleague says some permission changes were made to the scipy directories for the Anaconda-2.4.0 install. So, just a simple check of the scipy permissions may reveal the problem.